# Is my claim true about the maximum and minimum of the given function?

Tags: functions, trigonometry, inequality, maxima-minima

I have this three-variable function
$$f(x,y,z)=x^9 \cos (2 x y+x z)+\left(5 x^4+1\right) \cos (x y+x z)+\left(5 x^4+3\right)\\ \qquad+\left(4 x^3+1\right) \cos (x y+2 x z)+x^3 \cos (x z)+\left(2 x^2+7\right) \cos (2 x y+2 x z)\\ \qquad+\left(x^2+5\right) \cos (x y)+\left(2 x^2+7\right) \cos (2 x z)\\+\left(3 x^7+5 x^2+1\right) \cos (x y-x z)+(x+1) \cos (2 x y)$$
for $x,y,z>0$.

Now, since all the coefficients of the functions $\cos$ are positive, can I claim that the inequality $f_{-1}\leq f(x,y,z)\leq f_{+1}$ holds, where $f_{\pm1}$ are the function $f(x,y,z)$ when all the $\cos$ are $+1$ and $-1$?

Comment: What exactly is the motivation for proving the bounds of the function?

Comment: @AlbusDumbledore This is part of my equation, and I need to know the bounds of this function to apply it on the other side of the equation.

Comment: @Martha97  Since $f(x, y, z) \le f_{+} = f(x, 0, 0)$, the upper bound $f_{+}$ is sharp. But the lower bound $f_{-}$ is not sharp, since $\cos (xz)$ and $\cos(2xz)$ can not be both $-1$.

Comment: @RiverLi Thanks. That is why I asked this question since the arguments of $cos$ are related to each other.

Comment: @Martha97 Let $u = xy, v = xz$. Then $f(x, y, z) = g(x, u, v)$ with independent variables $x, u, v > 0$. We may obtain tighter lower bounds than $f_{-}$. But how to obtain sharp lower bounds?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, considering that the variables only take positive values, setting all the co-sines to 1 will provide an upper bound and setting all the co-sines equal to -1 will provide a lower bound.

Comment: Thanks. I asked this question since I had doubts about the situation like for example when $\cos x y =-1$ which happens when $xy$ is an odd multiple of $\pi$; on the other hand, we also have the term $\cos 2x y$ that for those values, it will be $+1$. So, does not this make a problem here?

Comment: @Martha97 There is no problem here. You can imagine every $\cos$ replaced by a constant in you expression, and each of these constants is multiplied by a positive number (polynomial in $x$, with positive coefficients and positive $x$),

Comment: @Martha97 A different issue is about the gap between the actual value of the expression and the upper/lower bounds that you obtain. since every $\cos$ takes a different argument, maybe there is no combination of $x,y>0$ that actually yields every $\cos$ equal to 1 ( or equal to -1).

Comment: @Martha97 Can you comment on why you have unaccepted the answer? It may be useful for people coming across the post in the future.

Comment: Please look at the comment by RiverLi, I will wait for other answers.

Comment: Ok @Martha97, but if you are interested in the sharpness of the upper and lower bounds you should probably edit your post and mention that aspect. This may attract answers related to the comment by RiverLi.